# AngularJS service returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service called `serviceCallJson` that gets data from a JSON file, and I have another service `validateIn` that validates input from the user based on the data present in the JSON.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

  var serviceCallJson = function($http) {
      this.getCustomers = function() {
        var promise = $http({
            method : 'get',
            url : '../viewersData/userPwdPair.json'
          })

         .success(function(data) {
            return data;
          }); 
    }
  }

  var validateIn = function (serviceCallJson) {
      this.called = function(username, password) {
            this.returnedData = serviceCallJson.getCustomers();
            console.log(this.returnedData); //undefined
            var i = 0;

            angular.forEach(this.returnedData, function(value, key){
              while (i < 10) {
                if(value[i].username == username) {
                  if(value[i].password == password) {
                   alert("Logged In");
                  }
                }

                i = i + 1;
              }
            });
      }

  }

    angular.module('assignment1App')
      .service ('serviceCallJson', serviceCallJson)

    angular.module('assignment1App')
    .service ('validateIn', ['serviceCallJson', validateIn])

}())
```

I have the following questions:

1) I don't understand why `returnedData' is`undefined`when I am returning the data fetched by the`serviceCallJson`service on`success`?

2) When I `console.trace()` in the `console`, I get the following result:

[image]

Why am I not able to see the stack trace? (I am expecting to see my controller function being called, but it returns an anonymous function)

**Solution to the first question**

Thanks for all your comments. They were very helpful in debugging my app. The following code made it work. I am still unable to figure out the second question.

`serviceCallJson` service

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var serviceCallJson = function($http) {
      this.getCustomers = function() {
        return $http({
            method : 'get',
            url : '../viewersData/userPwdPair.json'
          });
      };
  };

  angular.module('assignment1App')
    .service ('serviceCallJson', serviceCallJson);
}());
```

`validateIn` service:

```
(function() {
  "use strict"; 

  var validateIn = function (serviceCallJson) {
      this.called = function(username, password) {

             serviceCallJson.getCustomers()
              .then(function (returnedData) {
                var i = 0;
                var j = 0;

                angular.forEach(returnedData.data, function(value){
                  while (i < 10) {
                    if(value[i].username == username) {
                      if(value[i].password == password) {
                       console.log("Logged In");
                       j = j + 1;
                      }
                    }
                    i = i + 1;
                  }

                  if (j === 0) {
                    console.log("Username or password is wrong");
                  }
                });
              });   
      };

  };
      angular.module('assignment1App')
        .service ('validateIn', ['serviceCallJson', validateIn]);
}());
```

**Update - Second question**

`Console.trace()` was logging an anonymous function instead of the method names that are being called because I was calling it independently in the console. The following usage of `console.trace()` in my `validate` service gives the correct stack trace with all the function names and properties that are being invoked.

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var validate = function (fetchDataService) {
      this.verify = function(username, password) {
             console.trace();

             fetchDataService.getCustomers()
              .then(function (returnedData) {
                var i = 0;
                var count = 0;

                angular.forEach(returnedData.data, function(value){
                  while (i < 10) {
                    if(value[i].username == username) {
                      if(value[i].password == password) {
                       console.log("Logged In");
                       count = count + 1;
                      }
                    }
                    i = i + 1;
                  }

                  if (count === 0) {
                    console.log("Username or password is wrong");
                  }
                });
              });   
      };

  };
      angular.module('assignment1App')
        .service ('validate', ['fetchDataService', validate]);
}());
```

Comment: it looks like you defined a promise but never actually executed it.  `var promise = $http...` isn't going to actually going to make the server call.  also, the return is going to assign `data` to `promise`; `getCustomers` is still not returning anything.

Comment: Returning with an asynchronous call will almost always be undefined, you need to set up callback functions

Comment: and returning from inner function doesn't return to the outer one. return to success callback will do nothing

Comment: @Claies I made the `$http.get` request. When I `console.log(data)` in the `success` callback, I get the JSON data. Thanks for pointing out that the `getCustomers` method is not returning anything though.

Comment: @iam-decoder Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the comment. I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @Michelle when something is queued as an asynchronous event, it gets executed in parallel to the rest of the document, basically meaning that "while we fetch the output from `'../viewersData/userPwdPair.json'` we're gonna keep processing the rest of the javascript." when it's done, the function passed to the `success()` part will be called, it can't return anything because it has nothing to return to since the parser moved on from the initial return point and already marked that as `undefined`. to breach this, you pass in another function or `callback` that gets executed when you have the data

Comment: @Michelle an easy way to do it is change the declarative line to `this.getCustomers = function(callback) {` change the success line to `.success(callback)` and change how you call the service by doing: `this.returnedData = serviceCallJson.getCustomers(function(response){ console.log(response); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a better explanation: When you do an `$http` call, you are making an async function call. Async functions complete some time in the future. So consider the following:

```
var res = myAsyncFunction(..); // Let's say $http call takes 5 seconds.

// Execution is linear in JS, so $http cannot actually return 
// a "result" at this point.

console.log(res); //res is not the result we are expecting.
```

Before JS had promises, there was something called a callback hell:

```
asyncFn(..., function(res) {
  anotherAsyncFn(res, function(res2) {
    ... ({
      ... ({
        // After a bunch of async calls, lets print the final result:
        console.log(res24);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Now there are promises:

```
asyncFn(...)
  .then(anotherAsyncFn)
  .then(...)
  .then(...)
  ...
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

So in your case:

1) `$http` call returns a promise.
2) You return that promise from the service function.
3) Using `promise.then` you assign a callback to be called when promise is complete.

For your second question: 
Whatever language you use, if there's a syntactic sugar for async functionality, stack trace will be more complicated for them even though the code looks very simple. You can see it happen in C# async/await, JS promises/generators/async-await etc and possibly Go routines.

---

```
var serviceCallJson = function($http) {
  this.getCustomers = function() {
    // Return the promise
    return $http({
        method : 'get',
        url : '../viewersData/userPwdPair.json'
      })
     .success(function(data) {
        return data;
      }); 
  }
}

// In controller:
// Promise is returned. So you can use 'then'
// Learn how to use promises. You can check out kriskowal/q
serviceCallJson.getCustomers().then(function (data) {
  //do something with data
  $scope.myData = data;
});
```

Comment: within `then` will be `data.data` ... the return from success is useless and not part of promise chain

Comment: he can figure out those himself if he's into it.

Comment: that's a silly comment. You provided a code answer and it should at least work

Comment: This will work, takes the legwork out of setting up your own callback process

Comment: This does work, it's just a rushed answer. Sorry about the down vote. If you edit your answer, I can undo the down vote.